# Zend View Renderer Path appending /script

Tags: zend-framework, view, path

I am learning Zend. I wanted to learn how to use it as a standalone set of classes and so my boot strap is as follows. I have no config.ini From this configuration - I would presume that the path would be to the view script

/controllers/:action.:suffix

However I get errors that the following file does not exist

/controllers/scripts/:action.:suffix

Where is the directory /scripts being appended??

I have looked at every path method I can and i have set Nover/No controller as well.

```
set_include_path('library');
require ('library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();



$front_controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front_controller->setControllerDirectory('controllers');

$View = new Zend_View();

$Renderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$Renderer->setView($View);
$Renderer->setViewSuffix("php");
$Renderer->setNeverController(true);
$Renderer->setViewBasePathSpec('/controllers');
$Renderer->setViewScriptPathNoControllerSpec(':action.:suffix');

echo $Renderer->getViewBasePathSpec();
echo $Renderer->getViewScriptPathNoControllerSpec();




$front_controller->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Zend as an individual set of classes, the viewRender Class still expects your folder setup to be

whatever/scripts
Whatever/helpers

etc.

As such you cannot control absolute path to your views folder. So Zend is best used as a fuill MVC stack as default.

However if you don't need routing and views etc - Its loosely coupled nature makes for a great set of utilities.

Answer (score 0):

It is not located in your controllers folder. It is in the views controller.
    /application/views/scripts/ACTION.phtml